# Searching and counting matching lines

Tags: awk

Hello I am looking for a solution to this problem. I have an output that I sorted using `uniq -c`. The code looks like this `find $DIR -type f | file -b $files | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr` Could somebody tell me in what way i can access the value of the number in the prefix?
What my output look like:

```
  21  ASCII text
  19  C source, ASCII text
  16  ASCII text
  10  ASCII text, with very long lines
  9   HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with
  2   HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon
  1   C source, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Exprected output:

```
    ASCII text                                 : 21 
    C source, ASCII text                       : 19
    ASCII text                                 : 16 
    ASCII text, with very long lines           : 10
    HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with    : 9 
    HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon   : 2 
    C source, UTF-8 Unicode text               : 1
```

How can I save the values before the file types into a variables?

Comment: Please post example data and expected output.

Comment: *save the values before the file types into a variables* - and where are your variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
... | awk '{k=$1;                   # save counts        
            sub(/[^ ]+ /,"",$0);    # remove the counts
            $1=$1;                  # normalize spaces
            print $0 "\t:",k}' |    # print in new order
      column -ts$'\t'               # align tabs
```

will print

```
ASCII text                                : 21
C source, ASCII text                      : 19
ASCII text                                : 16
ASCII text, with very long lines          : 10
HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with   : 9
HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon  : 2
C source, UTF-8 Unicode text              : 1
```

ps. your `sort -n` seems out of place, `file` will return text, you don't want to sort numerically at this point.

Comment: is there a way to call a bash function in awk?

Comment: you can call bash commands within `awk` but depends on what you want to achieve this may or may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Combining your pipeline with a Bash loop allows you to run commands on the parts and assign the variables to the parts.

Given:

```
$ echo "$out" 
21  ASCII text
19  C source, ASCII text
16  ASCII text
10  ASCII text, with very long lines
9   HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with
2   HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon
1   C source, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

You can use `sed` to assign a delimiter (in this case, I will use `:`) and then read the pipeline:

```
while IFS=: read -r fcnt ftype; do 
    printf "\t%-41s : %s\n" "$ftype" "$fcnt"
done < <(echo "$out" | sed -e 's/^\([ [:digit:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1:\2/')
    ASCII text                                : 21  
    C source, ASCII text                      : 19  
    ASCII text                                : 16  
    ASCII text, with very long lines          : 10  
    HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with   : 9   
    HTML document, ASCII text, with very lon  : 2   
    C source, UTF-8 Unicode text              : 1
```

Then just replace the `echo "$out"` part with your pipeline.

You can also use a Bash regex of the same type rather than call `sed` if efficiency is a concern.